# How to get the nearest line to a feature?

Tags: arcobjects, arcmap, c#, query

I have features on map, and i want to get the nearest poly-line to each one.
How to write spatial query to get the nearest one.

I tried to use `ISpatialFilter` but i couldn't reach anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't know if this is still of interest but I got it working doing something like this: (you would just need to replace myPoint with your feature)

```
        IProximityOperator proximityOperator = myPoint as IProximityOperator;         
        ISpatialFilter spatialFilter = new SpatialFilterClass();
        spatialFilter.Geometry = (IGeometry)myGeometry;
        spatialFilter.GeometryField = myFeatureClass.ShapeFieldName;
        spatialFilter.SpatialRel = esriSpatialRelEnum.esriSpatialRelIntersects;
        IFeatureCursor myFeatureCursor = myFeatureClass.Search(spatialFilter, false);

        while ((feature = myFeatureCursor.NextFeature()) != null)
        {
            distance = proximityOperator.ReturnDistance(feature.Shape);

            if (distance > 0 && distance < closestDistance)
            {
                closestFeature = feature;
                closestDistance = distance;
            }
        }
```

Comment: This only examines features that intersect the spatial filter's geometry, which is not a stated requirement.  Unless there's a threshold distance, in which case you'd buffer the search feature, I don't think you should use a spatial filter at all.